# Django Sum Aggregation from Int to Float

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

So i save my fees in cents, but want to display them in Euro. The conversion problem is that it first divides the integer by 100 and then converts to a float. It should be the other way around. How can i do that?

The following code should illustrate my Problem:

```
>>> from django.db.models import F, FloatField, Sum
>>> from payment.models import Payment
>>> 
>>> paymentlist = Payment.objects.all()
>>> result = paymentlist.annotate(
...     fees_in_cents=Sum(F('fees'), output_field=FloatField())).annotate(
...         fees_in_euro=Sum(F('fees')/100, output_field=FloatField()))
>>> 
>>> print(result[0].fees_in_cents, result[0].fees_in_euro)
120.0 1.0
```

fees_in_euro should obviously be 1.20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide fees value by 100.0

**Example**:

```
result = paymentlist.annotate(
    fees_in_cents=Sum(F('fees'), output_field=FloatField())).annotate(
    fees_in_euro=Sum(F('fees') / 100.0, output_field=FloatField())
)
```